# How to make a 8 inch hole through a brick wall for venting

Tags: vent, brick, hole, hood

I am planning on Installing a Vent hood the manufacturer recommends 8 inch duct work.

I am looking for options to make this hole.

1) Diamond hole saw.

I couldn't find a diamond hole saw in 8 inch.

2) Core Drill
 
But I will get a clean hole. My question is how do I measure the thickness of exterior wall. I have brick which is about three inches. I measure the wall thickness near my garage with brick it comes to around 10 inches. Is this correct ?

Comment: Is hammer drill out of the question?  With a wide bit?  We talking square or round duct?

Comment: There are companies that specialize in cutting holes in all types of brick, stone,  or concrete They are not cheap but the do great work

Comment: 3” brick 1.5” air gap 1/2” sheathing 5.5” stud 1/2” drywall= 11” wall  you will want to be certain you don’t have a wall stud in the way of your proposed hole. An exhaust vent kit with a damper in it will provide some cover for mild imperfections in your brick hole   I generally drill a bunch of small holes around the perimeter of a circle drawn on the brick. Then chisel away the remainder between holes. Use angle grinder to perfect the opening for the duct.

Comment: I am looking for 8 inch diameter square hole. I can use Milwaukee M18 hammer drill but can’t find diamond hole saw with 8 inch diameter. @The Evil Greebo

Comment: Hole saws don’t cut square holes

Comment: https://www.bunnings.com.au/diy-advice/home-improvement/walls/how-to-cut-a-brick-wall-opening

Comment: Sorry round hole

Comment: You probably won't find a reasonably priced 8" diam hole saw bit even as a rental.  You're almost certainly going to have to do your best to cut a circle out using a small chisel bit.

Comment: Here is another idea  what if I get a 4 inch hole saw and make two holes from center of a 8 inch will it work ? @The Evil Greebo

Comment: You would have 2 4"d holes side by side, if you can get the bit to stay put on the 2nd hole.  Then you would need to cut out 2 inches (not 4) above and below the two existing holes, centered.  Then you still need to round out the hole into a circle.  Or you can get a chisel bit.  BTW I don't know if you can find 4" hole bores.  I couldn't when I had to do a 4" hole myself - so it was the chisel bit for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Roto hammer (rent from local tool rental company)
[image]

1+ Chisel bit(s)
[image]

1 8" circle drawn on the surface you wish to cut through

1+ hour of tedious, annoying, possibly painful labor

After you get your hole and ensure the vent fits, be prepared to seal any gaps with concrete caulk, or exterior vinyl caulk, or whatever suits your fancy.

Answer (score 0):

No problem.
Just go online and type 8" diamond wet coring bit.
You can go to Amazon and type it.

Depending how deep you need the core to be.  As you drill, don't forget to wet the spot and when the core bottoms out, take it out and break the round cut part with a chisel inserted on your drill.  Remove the debris and keep going.

Expect to pay couple hundred dollars  if not more for a decent bit.

You still need a mandrill for the blade of course.  These blades don't come with it.

To square off the hole, just use a regular 4 1/2 inch angle grinder disc.

[The measurement on your wall thickness sounds about right.]

Easy as pie.

And there you have it.

Take care.

From Amazon Website
[image: Angle grinder blade]

[image: Concrete bit]

Comment: OP states in comments that they want an 8" **square** hole.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, solution in my answer. Thanks.